# webapp form value to spreadsheet

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a webapp form and I'm looking for a way to push the value of the form into google spreadsheet.

My current attempt is to assign a name to each form input (a1,a2,a3...) then attempt to iterate the form values into an array like this:

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService
.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
.evaluate()
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
}

function writeForm(form) {

var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bKrGjBV*****');
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
var input = [''];
var ndata = form

for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){
var value = form.a+j
input.push(value)
}
for(var k=0;k<data.length;k++){
sheet.getRange(k+1,4).setValue(ndata[k]);
}
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 5);
}


function getData(){

return SpreadsheetApp
.openById('1bKrGjBV*****')
.getSheets()[0]
.getDataRange()
.getValues(); 
}
```

Index.html

```
 <body>
 <center><h1>Produce Inventory Form </h1></center>
 <style>
 table,th,td{border:1px solid black;}
 </style>
 <? var data = getData(); ?>
 <form id="invform">
 <input type = "submit" value="Submit" onclick 
 ="google.script.run.writeForm(this.parentNode)">
 <table align="center">
 <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>ChName</th><th>On Hand</th></tr>
 <? for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ ?>
 <tr>
 <th><?= data[i][0] ?></th>
 <th><?= data[i][1] ?></th>
 <th><?= data[i][2] ?></th>
 <th><input type = "text" style="width:40px" min="0" maxlength="3" name=a<?
 =i ?>>
 </tr>
 <? } ?>
 </table>
 </body>
```

With this method, the problem I'm getting into is

```
 var value = form.a+j
```

Doesn't do what I was hoping for, which is to assign a variable to form.a1, form.a2, form.a3, ... then push it into an array.

I'm pretty sure there's a better way but I have yet to find a solution. Apologize for the messy code, but I was focused on getting the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a following modification?

### Modification points :

1. For Index.html, `</form>` is missing.
2. About `form.a+j`, you can retrieve the values using `form["a" + j]`.
3. `ndata` is JSON like `{a1: "value", a2: "value"}`. So when `ndata` is imported to cells, it becomes undefined.
4. When several values are imported to cells, the importing efficiency becomes higher by using `setValues()`.

When these are reflected to your script, the modified script is as follows. The values inputted to forms are imported to "D1:D" of spreadsheet.

### Modified script :

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
}

function writeForm(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bKrGjBV*****');
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var input = []; // Modified
  // var ndata = form
  for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){
    var value = form["a" + j]; // Modified
    input.push([value]) // Modified
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 4, input.length, input[0].length).setValues(input); // Added
  // for(var k=0;k<data.length;k++) {
  //   sheet.getRange(k+1,4).setValue(ndata[k]);
  // }
  // var range = sheet.getRange(1, 5);
}

function getData(){
  return SpreadsheetApp
   .openById('1bKrGjBV*****')
   .getSheets()[0]
   .getDataRange()
   .getValues();
}
```

#### Index.html

```
<body>
  <center><h1>Produce Inventory Form </h1></center>
  <style>
    table,th,td{border:1px solid black;}
  </style>
  <? var data = getData(); ?>
  <form id="invform">
    <input type = "submit" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.writeForm(this.parentNode)">
    <table align="center">
      <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>ChName</th><th>On Hand</th></tr>
      <? for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ ?>
      <tr>
        <th><?= data[i][0] ?></th>
        <th><?= data[i][1] ?></th>
        <th><?= data[i][2] ?></th>
        <th><input type = "text" style="width:40px" min="0" maxlength="3" name=a<?= i ?>>
      </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </form> <!-- Added -->
</body>
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was able to push the values correctly with your modified code. I did have to change to setValue since I only had one column of data to push. I also changed (input) to (input[j]) so it wasn't just pushing the first value. I think I understand a bit more on how to work with html and java now.